# Swift 4 Image Picker Not Changing UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

For some reason in my new project this code is not working which has worked for me before. The current code does not change the ui of `profileImage`.

**Delegates**

```
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

**Code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

@IBAction func changeProfilePicture(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Profile picture tapped")

        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Picture", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { (action) in
            pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

   @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : Any]?) {

        self.profileImage.image = image
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

**Console Output**

> errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error
>   Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

**I have tried**

> ```
>    @objc func
>
>     internal func
>
>     @objc internal func
> ```

`self.profileImage.image = image` does not set the UI and change the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct delegate method

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

   if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
      self.profileImage.image = image
   }
   else
     if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
      self.profileImage.image = image
    }
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```